# how do you add status checks to a github repo

Tags: github

I need to add a status check to a github repo so you can merge a pull request only if jenkins regression passed successfuly.

Inside GitHub I'm going to 'settings' -> 'branches' and there I chose 'master' branch and checked the 'Require status checks to pass before merging' box. But then It tells me I have no status checks to choose from, but also doesnt let me add/configure..

So after looking up in google and stackoverflow I still haven't found an answer to 'How can I add github status checks to a repository'

Do I need to add some special github files for my repo?